# Задание по указателям - C (СИ)

Tags: c, строки

С клавиатуры вводится динамическая строка. Проверить, входит ли в нее цифры 5 и 7. При доступе к элементам использовать указатели.
Что не так?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
    char *str = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    gets(str);
    char*Ykaz[strlen(str)];
    printf("Vhodyat 7 ta 5?");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (*str[i] == 5 || *str[i] == 7)
            printf("Da, vhodyat");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Да, что не так? Почему бы Вам не поделиться с нами этой информацией?

Comment: А вот это - `char*Ykaz[strlen(str)];` - зачем? Чтоб указатели были? :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    #define MAXLEN  200
    char *str = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char));
    gets_s(str,MAXLEN);
    int has5 = 0, has7 = 0;
    for (char * c = str; *c; ++c)
    {
        switch(*c)
        {
            case '5': has5 = 1; break;
            case '7': has7 = 1; break;
        }
        if (has5 && has7) break;
    }
    if (has5) puts("String has '5'");
    if (has7) puts("String has '7'");
}
```

Примерно так.